# trying to create factorial calculator but fact dips below 0

Tags: c++

I'm new at c++, I'm trying to create a factorial calculator, but I'm having trouble calculating n! when n > 15.
Here's the Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int calculate_factorial(int num)
{
    int fact = num;
    for (int i = fact - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        cout << i << " " << fact << endl;
        fact *= i;
    }
    return fact;
}
int main()
{
    int num = 16;
    cout << calculate_factorial(num) << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: integer overflow...

Comment: A "sum" is what you get by *adding* a bunch of things together. This is a "product".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the fact that calling it a sum is just... no. Anyway, `int` can only go up to `2^31 - 1`, and that's only good for `12!`. Even changing it to `unsigned int` won't change that, and even using `unsigned long long int` would only allow you to go up to `20!`.

Your result is overflowing. You might wanna look into the GNU Multiple Precision library.

Comment: thx, sry for bad variable names and kindof being a noob

Comment: Note that the sizes of data types aren't guaranteed; the standards for how big some things are differ between operating systems (Linux, Mac OS, Windows), between 32-bit and 64-bit platforms, and can be even more different if you ever code for something weird.